# Prove that $\forall \beta \in I, \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha \subseteq A_\beta \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Here, $I \neq \emptyset$ and $\{A_\alpha: \alpha \in I\}$ is an indexed collection. Prove that $\forall \beta \in I$,
$$ \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha \subseteq A_\beta \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$$

Proof:

Let $x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ arbitrary. Then $x \in A_{\alpha_1}, A_{\alpha_2}, \dots$; in particular, $x \in A_{\alpha_i}$ for some $\beta = \alpha_i$. Thus $x \in A_\beta$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha \subseteq A_\beta$.

Furthermore, since $\beta \in I$ and $x \in A_\beta$, then necessarily $x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$, so $A_\beta \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...$?

Comment: I was trying to convey that $x \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, so I just added subscripts to them. Is that sensible?

Comment: No. When you add subscripts $1,2,3...$ you are assuming countability.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that. If I remove that statement, would the proof then be valid? Or explicitly state that $x \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in I$?

Comment: $x \in A_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha$ is the correct way to write the proof.

Comment: And for the second part you must take a new $x$, to only assume it belongs to $A_\beta.$

Comment: @AnneBauval does it not follow for the same $x$?

Comment: If you only prove that the same $x$ ($\in\cap_{\alpha\in I} 
A_\alpha$) belongs to $\cup _{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha,$ you won't have proved $A_\beta \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ but only $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought it would be valid because set inclusion is transitive, but I realize my mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta \in I$ and $x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}A_\alpha$, then $x \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in I$, hence $x \in A_\beta$.

If $\beta \in I$ and $x \in A_\beta$, then there is $\alpha = \beta \in I$ such that $x \in A_\alpha$, hence $x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}A_\alpha$.